# Specific url consistently rewritten to the very same result

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rss

When I am trying to access `http://localhost/ArtArchive/feed/`, I consistently get the very same Not Found error:
`The requested URL /ArtArchive/feed.xml/ was not found on this server.`
No matter what rewrite rule I give, I can't get this error to change.

The only existing .htaccess, located in the ArtArchive folder, starts like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /ArtArchive/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !debug.php

Rewriterule ^feed/$ ./feed.xml [L]
```

But if I try to change the rewriterule with...
`Rewriterule ^feed/$ ./food.xml [L]`
... then I am *still* getting an error about **feed.xml/** not being found.

Might the web browser remember an old redirection?
Clearing the cache of firefox will clear *any other* cached redirection. Only this this very url remain unchangeable.
It doesn't even look like the browser is trying to redirect anything; the urls in the adress bar remains unchanged, and the developpement console looks devoid of anything useful.

Is my rewrite rule even right to begin with?
I tried the very same syntax with a different directory :
`Rewriterule ^food/$ ./feed.xml [L]`
and this one properly redirects `http://localhost/ArtArchive/food/` to my xml file.

---

I was suggested to enable rewrite logging, but am clueless as to how it works.
I'm running the site on Wamp.

Comment: Did you try restarting Apache?

Comment: @Kai One does not need to restart the http server process when changing a dynamic configuration file. That is their whole point.

Comment: I think you should first try to find out where that `feed.xml` actually comes from. The issue here is that this rule you show does an _internal_ redirection, it would never result in the given error message, whether it applies or not. So: open your browsers development console, select the networking tab and examine the request, especially the response. Also enaling rewrite logging in your http server certainly makes sense for debugging purposes, see the official documentation of the rewriting module for that. Add gained information to the question itself, not into comments here.

Comment: @arkascha I can't find anything new in the Network tab. As for rewrite logging, apache configuration is alien to me, and the documentation isn't made for novices; I have no idea what files I'm supposed to change or look at. I'm working on wamp if that helps with anything.

Comment: You implemented an _internal_ redirection, those do not change the URL visible in the browser. What makes you certain that the object `/ArtArchive/feed.xml` actually exists? In the end you need to 1. locate your http servers error log file (look for the `ErrorLog` directive in the apache configuration) and yu really should find out how to enable "rewrie logging" (there are many tutorials about that), it allows you to follow step by step what is actually happening in your rewriting engine. Sorry, but that is nothing we can take you by the hand. You need to start yourself and work into the field